# DIV not pushing footer down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made one page and in the page i used toggle by jquery. my page is looking perfect but when i click on button to show content then the div is fixed and my content is expand and  hide behind the footer.

here is image.[image]

please help me to find out the solution

please click this link for html and css

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/ybo1xkwg/1/`
```

Comment: Post your markup/CSS

Comment: add your website link or make a code snippet

Comment: It seems like a problem with floating content, without a clear: both|left|right after the content.

Comment: Possibly issue of `height` or `overflow` not being `auto` for the main container. And yes no code no help.

Comment: Give position absolute.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ybo1xkwg/1/   please click this link for html and css

Comment: Please read this [mcve]

Comment: It seems ok here :https://jsfiddle.net/06dskcy5/

Comment: i didnt put the footer code thats why it seem okay.

Comment: So where is footer?

Comment: here is updated one..   https://jsfiddle.net/06dskcy5/1/

Comment: @Aziz if your project is online then show us a URL

Comment: give me a some time i will put it live

Comment: Yes because here in demo it looks Ok.

Answer (score 0):

I got the sloution,
The main problem is height of my div.When i checked by inspect element then in element.style it show the `height:1359;`. So I give it `height:100% !important;` to my div.

Now problem is solved